# How to get column header if sub-string is found in sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am attempting to get the column header of a cell in Sheet1 when that cell contains a substring that is defined by cell Sheet2!A2. I have used this formula successfully for cases where the string=substring however when there are other characters it fails:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$1,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$J$8=$A2,COLUMN(Sheet1!$C$2:$J$8)-COLUMN($A2)+1),1))
```

I have attempted to replace the IF test condition with COUNTIF(Sheet1!$C$2:$J$8, $A2)>0, which successfully finds all relevant substrings but always returns the column header of the third column. I am not sure why this change occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNTIF` will not return an array.  Try this array-entered formula (confirm by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$1,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$J$8)),COLUMN(Sheet1!$C$2:$J$8)),1))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you very much.